# Automorphism of division ring with characteristic p - prime number

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$(D,+,.)$ is finite division ring with characteristic $p$ - prime number. Prove that maping $f: D \rightarrow D, x \mapsto x^p $  is automorphism of the ring D.

Proof looks easier for $ ({\displaystyle \mathbb {Z}_p,+,.)}$ but how to make it general? Are there some differences?
I know that I have to show that mapping is ring homomorphism and bijective.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Partial hint: to show it's bijective, it's enough to show it's injective, hence to show the kernel is trivial.

Comment: Why is enough to show that it is only injective. Shouldn't  I show that is also surjective, it means that the Imf is whole D? Thanks

Comment: The ring $D$ is finite. Can't you use Wedderburn's theorem by the way ?

Comment: @Max Using Wedderburn would be an overkill. If this is a homework problem, I would guess you are expected _not_ to use it.

Comment: @Waney Since $D$ is finite, if a map is injective, it's also surjective.

Comment: @Wojowu, oh, yes of course, sorry, I have forgotten that D is finite. Moreover I have already heard about Wedderburn's theorem (that every finite division ring is field), but not officially in school, so I think that we cannot use it.

Comment: But only of interest how the Wedderburn's theorem can be use it in this case? Thanks.

Comment: @Wojowu : yes, but if you are allowed to use it, it becomes a really easy homework problem. Waney: to use Wedderburn's theorem allows you to say $D$ is a finite field, in which the result is easy. For this exercise, the hard part is not bijectivity, it's the fact that it's a morphism, which is way easier for commutative rings